# How to forecast a rental weekly sales demand using a 4 year history data?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, predictive-models, history, random-allocation

I need to estimate the weekly demand required for a specific product in a specific week at a specific location.

I have the past 4 years daily data of each product at each location.
For example: number of past years available =4, number of locations = 6, types of products = 25,
and number of orders each day at respective location is available.

Could you please tell me how to forecast this data? what is the suitable forecasting model or tool to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many suitable forecasting models e.g. regression, random forests, decision trees...

They all work in a similar manner. You could use your "number of orders each day at respective location" to calculate the weekly sales for each location - that weekly sales figure will be your response, or target. As you say you want to predict for specific weeks, presumably you can categorise these weeks e.g. "week 1" to "week 52".

Your predictors, or features, would be location, product type, and week.

You then build your model using your four years of historic data, and use it to produce predictions for whatever combination of week, location and product type you're interested in.

That's the simple answer. You could also look to split your historic data into training and test sets to try and fine-tune your model.

You could look to test if including additional features improves your model. e.g. maybe sales in the previous week would be a useful feature, if you have that data available when you're making new predictions.

Things may get a bit more complicated if you think there are seasonal patterns between weeks that isn't fully captured by including your "week" predictor. If this is the case you could look into time-series modelling e.g. ARIMA.